# Sequence slider stopping after second slide

Tags: jquery, css

I have the sequence slider setup for autoplay and it will only slide to the second slide and then stops. There are seven slides that it should be sliding through.

Here is the code for the options I have set up but I can't see why it is stopping after slide 2. Maybe a problem with the CSS transitions? I'm stumped!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlayDelay: 1000,
    nextButton: true,
    prevButton: true,
    preloader: true
};
var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");

sequence.afterLoaded = function(){
    $(".prev, .next").fadeIn(500);
}
});
```

The website is here - http://aald.captechnix.com/

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue earlier today and had a quick look at the source code. It looks like sequence.js is just looking at the direct children of each frame in order to determine when animations have ended before moving onto the next frame. Looking at your example it seems you don't have any transitions on any of the direct children of each slide so internally sequence.js never sets the "animationEnded" property to true for these elements and refuses to move onto the next slide.

Make sure all direct children of each slide has at least an .animate-in transition and that a value for that element is actually transitioned. So in your case try adding the following css (I've left out vendor prefixes):

```
#sequence .width {
 transition: all 1s linear;
 z-index: 9999;
}
#sequence .animate-in .width {
 z-index: 9998; /* or some other property as long as it changes */
}

#sequence-theme img {
 transition: all 0.1s linear;
 opacity: 0;
}
#sequence-theme .animate-in img {
 opacity: 1; /* or some other property as long as it changes */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution here is if we add the following function:

```
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("your-button-id").click();}, 5000);
```

This way we simulate button click each nth time. And if you wish to hide the buttons, you can just add visibility hidden to the arrow container:

```
.banner-arrow-container {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```