# Sequence.JS not animating (or doing anything really)

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm working on creating a site using [Sequence.JS](http://sequencejs.com). I've looked over the markup a dozen times, I've got a few `animate-in` and `animate-out` classes so it should do **SOMETHING** when it loads. Here's my HTML markup:

```
<div id="feature">
    <div id="featurewrap">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul id="slides" class="sequence">
                <li class="slide1">
                    <div class="headline left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h2>Testing the slider headline</h2>
                            <p class="blurb">This is an example of the captions you can have on the slider</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/slides/slide1.jpg" />
                </li>
                ...Slide2...
                ...Slide3...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery markup:

```
$(function(){
    var options = {
        preloader: false,
        hideFramesUntilPreloaded: false,
        fallback: {
            theme: "fade",
            speed: 500
        },
        pauseOnHover: true,
        animateStartingFrameIn: true,
        transitionThreshold: 250,
        reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlayDelay: 6000
    };
    var sequence = $("#slider").sequence(options).data("sequence");
});
```

Additionally, here's the site I'm currently working on: [cirkut.net/sub/2013northwood/](http://www.cirkut.net/sub/2013northwood/)

There's no console errors. As far as I can tell all scripts are loading properly and are in order. Sequence should be adding `animate-in` classes to the first slide. Nothing is currently happening, even with `autoPlay` on.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've added a class of `.sequence-canvas` to the `ul` and now the first slide animates in.  However, I now have the problem of sequence.js not animating to the next slide after 6000ms.

**P.S. UPDATE**
Okay, now it's randomly working.

For anyone who reads this question in the future, **MAKE SURE** you add a class of `.sequence-canvas` to the `ul` that contains the slides!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this one?

[Sequence slider stopping after second slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237469/sequence-slider-stopping-after-second-slide)

**To sum up:**

Make sure all direct children of each slide has at least an `.animate-in` transition and that a value for that element is actually transitioned.